# Since g:remoteFunction in Grails 2.4.X is deprecated what should i use instead?

Tags: grails

Since [g:remoteFunction](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html) is deprecated what should I use instead? And please give an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should use your own javascript AJAX functions, as they provide way more flexibility

EXAMPLE

used to be:

```
<input type="button" value="go!" onclick="${g.remoteFunction( controller:'my', action:'go', params:[..] )}"/>
```

should be (for example in `JQuery`):

```
<g:javascript>
  function go(){
    $.ajax({ 
      url:'${g.createLink( controller:'my', action:'go', params:[..] )}',
      data:{ param1:param1 }
    });
  }
 </g:javascript>

 <input type="button" value="go!" onclick="go()"/>
```

Comment: please could you give an example

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on Injecteers answer actually the data:{} is what is posting information to it so may clash with params:[..]} :

```
<g:javascript>
  function go(){
   var javaScriptVariable='123'
    $.ajax({ 
      url:'${g.createLink( controller:'my', action:'go')}',
      data:{ 
        param1: "${params.params1}",
        param2: javascriptVariable 
      }
    });
  }
 </g:javascript>
```

`data:{}` can also be `data: $('form').serialize();` where serialize function grabs all the form elements and serializes it for you as params to be passed back.