# ajax callback in grails

Tags: ajax, grails

i have the below ajax code in my GSP , how in my controller's action `testAjax` send `success` or `failure` to that code so the functions in **success** or **failure** will be executed , here is the ajax :

```
$.ajax({
    contentType: false ,
    async :false,
    processData: false,
    url:'/myApp/photos/testAjax',
    type:'POST' ,
    //dataType: 'JSON', 
    data: uploadedFiles, 
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if(typeof data.error == 'undefined')
        {// Success so call function to process the form
            submitForm(event, data);
            alert (" data " + data);
       }
        else
        {
            // Handle errors here
            console.log('ERRORS: ' + data.error);
        }

        },

error: function(data,  textStatus,  errorThrown) {
   // Handle errors here
        console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
   }

});
```

here is the action in the controller :

```
def testAjax() {
    println ("ajax data "+  params)
}
```

Comment: Since remoteFunction is deprecated please check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25245800/2166188).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def action(){
    render(status: 200, text: 'your text')
}
```