# Grails POST data via Jquery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails, grails-3.1

App info:

- Grails 3.1.8
- Jquery 2.2.0

I have a Grails form which I would like to POST via AJAX. I am able to do this and the data does persist in the database. Code to post is below:

```
<g:javascript>

    $('#insertSchool').submit(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/school/saveSchool',
            data: $("#insertSchool").serialize(),
            success: function(savedSchool) {


            }

        });

    });

</g:javascript>
```

Controller code:

```
def saveSchool(School newSchool) {

    def theSchool = schoolService.saveSchool(newSchool)

    render theSchool as JSON
}
```

In the success function I would like to redirect to another page and send a message across saying the school has been saved. I'm new to Jquery so I'm unable to implement this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: window.location = '/school/success';

Comment: Why would you use Ajax if you're redirecting user somewhere else?

Comment: For the error method which I have not yet implemented. I'd like to display the error messages on the form

Comment: Please have a look at Flash message here : http://docs.grails.org/1.3.9/ref/Controllers/flash.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use remote function to redirect another page.

```
<script>
   $('#insertSchool').submit(function () {
        ${remoteFunction(action: 'xyz', controller:'xyz',method: 'post',
            params: 'variable:value',onSuccess: 'redirectFunction();')};
    }

   function redirectFunction(){
        alert("the school has been saved");  
       // AGAIN USE A REMOTE FUNCTION TO REDIRECT ON ACTION (your gsp page)
   }

 </script>
```

Comment: I'm using Grails 3.1.8 and the remoteFunction tag has been deprecated. See - http://docs.grails.org/3.0.0.M1/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html

Comment: this link may help you->\http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245689/since-gremotefunction-in-grails-2-4-x-is-deprecated-what-should-i-use-instead