# ERROR : No tag library found for namespace: g

Tags: grails

I'm trying to render a simple form.gsp page from my test controller & getting below error in my gsp page.

```
URI
/test/form
Class
org.grails.taglib.GrailsTagException
Message
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.gsp.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: [views/test/form.gsp:25] [views/test/form.gsp:25] Tag [remoteFunction] does not exist. No tag library found for namespace: g
Caused by
[views/test/form.gsp:25] [views/test/form.gsp:25] Tag [remoteFunction] does not exist. No tag library found for namespace: g
```

Have tried adding below code under `<head>` tag

```
<g:javascript library='jquery' />
<r:layoutResources/>
```

Also tried adding runtime jquery dependency in `build.gradle` file but all in vain

Using below version

```
grailsVersion=3.1.10
gradleWrapperVersion=2.13
```

Would appreciate any help !! 
   P.S:- I'm just a beginner in Grails Groovy So apologies my negligence !!

Comment: Could you post your code for rendering the form?

Comment: remoteFunction http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245689/since-gremotefunction-in-grails-2-4-x-is-deprecated-what-should-i-use-instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have not installed the `ajax-tags` plugin.  You will want something like `runtime 'org.grails.plugins:ajax-tags:1.0.0.RC1'` in the `dependencies` section of `build.gradle`.

Comment: Thank you Jeff !! I was missing this plugin. Many Thanks :):)